# FadeIn animation not work swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, animation, fadein

Below is my code.
The fade out effect works fine. The fade in effect however is not animated .
I can not solve this problem. Thanks to all those that will help me.
Alpha is set 0 in storyboard

```
extension UIView {

    func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 3.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: completion)  }

    func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 2.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 3.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

Comment: r u trying to do the fade in after the fade out directly ?

Comment: no fadeout after fadein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `UIView.animationWithDuration` directly after it was called will cancel the previous animation even if you supply a delay in the function call. However, you can either use the completion function like @Daniel Hall suggested:

```
myView.fadeIn() {  _ in
   myView.fadeOut() 
}
```

Or if you do the fadeOut in a different method that is being triggered by some event exactly after fadeIn you can use dispatch_after to execute after delay time ( which should be the fadeIn duration in your case)

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.myView.fadeOut()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me inside a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 3.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)  
    }

    func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 2.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 3.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}

let liveView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)))
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = liveView

let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50))
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
newView.alpha = 0

liveView.addSubview(newView)
newView.fadeIn { _ in newView.fadeOut{ _ in newView.fadeIn() } }
```

It fades in, fades out on completion of the fade-in, then fades back in on completion of the fade-out.

Perhaps the issue it where / when you are calling the `fadeIn()` method on your view, and not a problem with your extension itself.

Comment: That problem could be there , call it inside the touchesBegan () function with this code : mylabel.fadein ( ) ; mylabel.fadeout ( )

Comment: @LuigiFestinante  Ah, well that's your issue there!  You are calling `fadeIn()` and then immediately calling `fadeOut()`.  So it makes sense that you aren't seeing the fade in animate and finish.  Try this instead:  `my label.fadein { _ in mylabel.fadeOut() }`.  That passes the `fadeOut()` command inside the completion handler for `fadeIn()`, instead of running it immediately.

Comment: @LuigiFestinante  Great - glad it's working!  Would appreciate if you could upvote and / or accept my answer  :)